# how to display image on popup for different field click in list

Tags: jquery, spring

```
      <table>
          <c:forEach items="${couponlist}" var="list">
          <tr>
            <td><a href="#myPopup" data-rel="popup" data-position-              to="window" ><input type="text" name="couponName" value="${list.couponName}"     readonly></a>

           <div data-role="popup" id="myPopup">
            <p>This is my Coupon Image!</p> 
             <a href="#pageone" data-role="back"  class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui -                  shadow ui-btn-a ui-icon-delete ui-btn-icon-notext ui-btn-right" ></a>
            <img src="${list.ImagePath}" style="width:800px;height:400px;"      alt="Skaret View" id="src" >
           </div>
          </td>               

           </tr>
         </c:forEach>
         </table>
```

i am using spring mvc for my web application.i am fetching list of coupon from database with name and imagepath.i am displaying all name in list.i want to display image in popup window,on click of name.i tried following code but it display only first records image for every name.i want separate image for each name.please help me to solve it

Comment: Got your problem... :)

Comment: plz help me to solve it.

Comment: the problem is with your `href="#myPopup"` and `id="myPopup"`. Same is getting applied to all images.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Added `varStatus="loop"` in forEach and creating `id` dynamically like 
`id="myPopup${loop.index}"`

```
<table>
     <c:forEach items="${couponlist}" var="list" varStatus="loop">
          <tr>
            <td><a href="#myPopup${loop.index}" data-rel="popup" data-position-              to="window" ><input type="text" name="couponName" value="${list.couponName}"     readonly></a>

           <div data-role="popup" id="myPopup${loop.index}">
            <p>This is my Coupon Image!</p> 
             <a href="#pageone" data-role="back"  class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui -                  shadow ui-btn-a ui-icon-delete ui-btn-icon-notext ui-btn-right" ></a>
            <img src="${list.ImagePath}" style="width:800px;height:400px;"      alt="Skaret View" id="src" >
           </div>
          </td>               

           </tr>
         </c:forEach>
         </table>
```

Comment: it works fine,,thank you so much for your great help.

Comment: Oh...Great. Glad to know it... :). you can accept the answer if you want so that it will be marked as answered.

Comment: Hello Mahesh...actually I am not getting your issue with page refresh.

Comment: above code works fine ..but when we redirects to this page from another page, popup will not work.but when we refresh the page then it will work fine

Comment: but in both cases page is getting rendered...correct. then what is the difference between coming to this page from another AND pressing F5?